# tabs doesnt get fixed in ionic inside ion-content

Tags: tabs, fixed, ionic-framework

I have been trying making ion-tabs fixed inside ion-content but it hardly seems posssible. So is there any way of making tabs fixed inside a scollable content in ionic?

```js
        $( "ion-content" ).scroll(function() {

            var scrollWidth =  $(".main-content").height()-$(".header-bar").height();

            if (parseInt($(this).scrollTop()) > scrollWidth ) {
                $("#fixedAboutTabs").addClass("fixed");

                });


            }
            else {
                $("#fixedAboutTabs").removeClass("fixed");
                });
```

```css
.fixed{
    left: 0;
    top:44px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ion-view>
 
    <div class="header-bar">
        <button class="button button-clear arrow-btn" ng-click="goBack()"> <img src="img/arrow.png" class="arrow-img"> </button>
        <h1 class="title">{{product.productName}}</h1>
    </div>


    <ion-content on-scroll="onScroll()" overflow-scroll="true" has-bouncing="false">
        <div class="main-content">

            <img src="img/video.png" class="video-img">

            <div class="product-info">
                //some content here
            </div> <!--product info closes -->

           
        </div> <!--main content closes-->

        <div id="staticAboutTabs" class="demo-tabs">
            <ul>
               //customized tabs (want to make this tabs fixed bewlow header-bar)
            </ul>
        </div>


  
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Instead of ion-tabs i have used my own customized tabs. let me know if the ion-tabs or any custom made tabs can be fixed inside scrollable ion-content

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: @Daenarys i have added some code snippets now.. check if ya can help me now

Comment: Do you want footer tab or header tab ?That code snippet  is not giving exact idea of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by placing the to-be-fixed content inside `<div slot="fixed"> </div>`

```
<ion-content>
<div slot="fixed">
    <ion-tabs #tabs tabsPlacement="top">
        <ion-tab-bar slot="top" tabsHighlight="true">
          <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
            <ion-label>Tab1</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
          <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
            <ion-label>Tab2</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>
      </ion-tabs>
      </div>
</ion-content>
```